# I ............................... the new shop

Tags: present-perfect, been-vs-gone

Which one of five options fit best in the blanks in the following sentences.

> A : I ........... not ............ the new shop.Would you like to
>   check it out?
>
> B : No. I ........... already ............. there.

1. have gone (to)
2. have been (to / in)

---

I wouldn't say "I have gone to the new shop" if I were outside but in a negative sentence like above, it sounds  a bit OK  to say " I have not gone there". In the end "you have not been there" because you have not gone to the shop.

The second sentence is likely that " I have already been there"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you've written below the example sentences. You should add some punctuation. “To” usually denotes motion, “in” position. Also, as I understood the question, the sentence following “B:” also requires one of the three options, not necessarily distinct from the previously used one. Hence “I have already been there,” doesn't compose a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way I was taught was that 'been' is used to describe a visit that has been returned from, but 'gone' is used to describe a visit that has not been returned from.

eg:

"I have been to France" implies I have visited France, but I am no longer there;

"I have gone to France" implies I am still in France.

So in your example, 'been' would be correct. Using 'gone' (*I have not gone to the new shop*) would only imply that the speaker is not currently at the new shop, but does not address whether he/she has been there previously.

Comment: I see.what about the second sentence B says